# is there a way to make an infinite loop in django

Tags: django, while-loop, tags, countdown

I want to make a countdown for my website and I can't do it.

Please help me

I try with a tag "for" but you need the "while" loop which has no tag in django

Comment: Please show the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a countdown that is visible for visitors in your website, you will actually need Javascript code in your HTML template.

Here is an example function that would help you:

```
<div id="countdown"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var count={{countdown_end_time}};
var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer() {
    count=count-1;
    if (count <= 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        $('div #countdown').html('Timeout reached');
        return;
    }
    min = Math.floor(count/60);
    secs = (count % 60)
    $('div #countdown').html('You have ' + (min < 10 ? '0'+min : min) + ':' + (secs < 10 ? '0'+secs : secs) + ' minutes left')
}
</script>
```